# The point of climax/resolution in an advert

Tags: terminology, advertising

I was wondering if anyone on here knows the technical name for the point in a TV advert where the narrative is resolved and the audience can understand what the message is and what is being sold?

For example, the point in [this advert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uq-9QBUmELA) at about 1:18 in which the main character returns to the screen holding the product.

Comment: What's wrong with climax or resolution?

Comment: I might call it a "product reveal" in the example you gave, but your question is pretty ambiguous

Comment: I'm struggling to find any information on it so was wondering if there was a more universally accepted term for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Climax is a commonlly used term. There is a story telling model that include 4 points.

1. Introduction
2. Development
3. Climax
4. Conclusion

There are some other models like

1. Setup
2. Conflict

   - Climax can be inside here
3. Resolution

But it does not necesary means that the product need to be shown there. **That depends on the type of advert** that you are promotioning.

Typical info ads can start with an exagerated problem, where the person strugles, then if the product is presented as a solution yes, can be on the climax or on some models a step after conflict, called solution.

But is some other ads the product can be shown just after the introduction (or the product itself is the introduction), and the development can go based on the product, like a typical car add.

Google something like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=storytelling+model

Another term similar can be "peak".

---

Edited. On that particular example, the product is actualy not showed but after, like a conclusion. That is not the "peak".

It has a looooong introduction, a little development (probably arround the dog walking) a very small climax, (probably that is not when the guy goes for the drink, but on the lateral plane, with the guy with his shoes on).

---

Aditional note. Every model is not a stiff recipy. It is ment to be broken and explored.